Why does Nasir get a pair of sneakers in prison?
In the TV series The Night Of (2016), Nasir Khan receives a pair of sneakers passed on to him by a prison guard; they come from a powerful inmate who used to be a boxing champion.
Nasir is seen wearing them when taking a shower.
I am wondering why Nasir wears them while showering and what a pair of sneakers symbolises.
